# HTML- footer se sobrepõe ao conteudo do HTML

Tags: html, css

O footer que tenho sobrepoe-se ao conteudo do body. Ja coloquei o footer dentro do body e fora dele e mesmo assim tenho este problema. por favor veja a imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu6r1.jpg , como tenho este formulario os botoes deixam de funcionar porque o footer esta sobreposto.

codigo footer:

```
  <footer align:center>
    <p> &#174; Galaxy Books Store</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um pouco estranho esse "align:center" fora do atributo "style". Mas independente disso, o mais provável é que seu footer tenha um position "absolute" ou "fixed".
Como vc só colocou uma imagem não dá pra saber exatamente qual o problema, mas vc poderia tentar genericamente com:

```
footer{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Isso no css, obviamente... Se vc quiser estilos inline seria:

```
<footer style="display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; clear: both;">
    <p> &#174; Galaxy Books Store</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: era a posição sim